# Is it possible to check if server is running on ECS Fargate

Tags: java, kotlin, amazon-ecs

Currently migrating my server with java/ kotlin from Elastic Beanstalk with EC2 to ECS Fargate. In the application we had the following code to check if the instance is running on AWS or locally:

```
Regions.getCurrentRegion() != null
```

This code is sadly only for EC2 instances, so was wondering if there is something similar for ECS Fargate or if we should just remove those checks in our codebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check, inside your code, if the code is running in ECS Fargate you could check for the existence of the `ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4` [environment variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4-fargate.html).

Comment: Thanks seems like a good and simple solution since I only need to check if it runs on it

Answer (score 0):

To check if a container exists or is running in ECS Fargate using Java or Kotlin, you can use the AWS SDK for Java. Below is a Java example that lists running tasks for a specific ECS cluster and service.

First, make sure to add the AWS SDK dependency to your Maven pom.xml or Gradle build file. For Maven, it would be:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ecs</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.3</version> <!-- use the latest version -->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Java Code example:**

List running tasks for a specific ECS Cluster and Service:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.ecs.AmazonECS;
import com.amazonaws.services.ecs.AmazonECSClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.ecs.model.ListTasksRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.ecs.model.ListTasksResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.ecs.model.DescribeTasksRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.ecs.model.DescribeTasksResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.ecs.model.Task;

import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AmazonECS ecsClient = AmazonECSClientBuilder.defaultClient();

        // Replace these with your cluster and service name
        String clusterName = "your-cluster-name";
        String serviceName = "your-service-name";

        // List running tasks
        ListTasksRequest listTasksRequest = new ListTasksRequest()
            .withCluster(clusterName)
            .withServiceName(serviceName)
            .withDesiredStatus("RUNNING");

        ListTasksResult listTasksResult = ecsClient.listTasks(listTasksRequest);
        List<String> taskArns = listTasksResult.getTaskArns();

        if (taskArns.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No tasks are currently running.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Running tasks: " + taskArns);

            // Describe tasks for more details
            DescribeTasksRequest describeTasksRequest = new DescribeTasksRequest()
                .withCluster(clusterName)
                .withTasks(taskArns);

            DescribeTasksResult describeTasksResult = ecsClient.describeTasks(describeTasksRequest);
            List<Task> tasks = describeTasksResult.getTasks();

            for (Task task : tasks) {
                System.out.println("Task " + task.getTaskArn() + " is currently " + task.getLastStatus());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This outputs the ARNs of all the running tasks for the given service and cluster and the current status for each running task.**